# UISplitViewController push multiple detail views iPad?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, detailview

i have a requirement to load multiple viewControllers on detailViewController on a splitView. somethingLike[image]

when the alarm is on , so that i can push the related view controller on detailView. left side view is a uitableview.

my code is here on AppDelegate.m

```
#import "splitDetailViewController.h"
#import "splitTableViewController.h"

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

  splitTable=[[splitTableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
  UINavigationController *splitTableNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:splitTable];

  splitDetails=[[splitDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *splitDetailNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:splitDetails];


  self.splitViewController.delegate=splitDetails;

  splitViewController=[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];

  splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:splitTableNav,splitDetailNav, nil];





  [self.window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
  }
```

sorry, this is the first time am developing iPad apps, am little bit confused about how to use splitview. how will i call the multiple viewControllers on detail view. for timer, alarm,share , each have different view controllers.

hope i will get some help!

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for the solution to a similar problem. In my case i wanted tableview to link to multiple detailviews depending on the selection. I could overlay the data on one viewcontroller but was seeking a better solution. Here is what i did. Its simple and works much better then some of the complex and outdated options i found so far.

I simply gave a storyboard ID in the identity inspector to the viewcontroller that i wanted showing up in the detailview ("second") and upon didSelectRowAtIndexPath i simply added:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TimeDetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];

    [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
 }
```

So when someone presses a cell in the master view, the detail view is pushed.

A simple if statement can switch which view is shown:

```
if ([[self.selfRootMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual: @"Second Choice"]) {
    TimeDetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];

    [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
 } else if ([[self.selfRootMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual: @"First Choice"]) {
     TimeDetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"first"];

     [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
 };
```

You could simply use buttons, switches or anything else instead of a table view but the point is that by adding a "Storyboard ID" in the "Identity Inspector"

and simply instantiating the view controller by referencing the "Storyboard ID" and then pushing it to the split view controller at index 1 (detail side) its simple and quick

```
TimeDetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];

[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Nice solution... i like it

Answer (score 1):

okay, myself found one solution, it works fine

http://kshitizghimire.com.np/uisplitviewcontroller-multipledetailviews-with-navigation-controller/

thankyou

Comment: please help me how can i use UIspliteviewcontroler in ipad. Now i want to add 2 UItableview. When i click the leftside UItableview i want to show rightside UItableview. how can i do this. please give me some idea. And in above the screen shot how you did that. Please tell me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @sathis  just create the objects for both of your view controllers and add this to UISplitViewController. self.splitViewController=[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
    
    splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects: TableViewController1,TableViewController2, nil];

Comment: then [sef.window addSubView:self.splitViewController.view] in you'd app delegate

Answer (score 1):

This is my Solution, hope it helps :   https://github.com/selfdealloc/MultipleDetailViewsUsingStoryboards